# Deleting equal number of rows based on column condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to reduce the size of my dataframe and need to maintain an equal number of each class (label). How do I remove an equal number of rows based on the column "label". In other words, I need there to be an equal distribution of class labels in the resulting dataframe.

I have the following dataframe:

```
    pd.DataFrame([{'label': 0, 'pixel1': 0, 'pixel2': 0, 'pixel3': 0, 'pixel4': 0},
 {'label': 1, 'pixel1': 0, 'pixel2': 0, 'pixel3': 0, 'pixel4': 0},
 {'label': 2, 'pixel1': 0, 'pixel2': 0, 'pixel3': 0, 'pixel4': 0},
 {'label': 3, 'pixel1': 0, 'pixel2': 0, 'pixel3': 0, 'pixel4': 1},
 {'label': 4, 'pixel1': 0, 'pixel2': 0, 'pixel3': 0, 'pixel4': 0},
 {'label': 5, 'pixel1': 0, 'pixel2': 0, 'pixel3': 0, 'pixel4': 5},
 {'label': 6, 'pixel1': 0, 'pixel2': 0, 'pixel3': 0, 'pixel4': 0},
 {'label': 7, 'pixel1': 0, 'pixel2': 0, 'pixel3': 0, 'pixel4': 0},
 {'label': 8, 'pixel1': 0, 'pixel2': 0, 'pixel3': 0, 'pixel4': 0},
 {'label': 9, 'pixel1': 0, 'pixel2': 0, 'pixel3': 0, 'pixel4': 0},
 {'label': 0, 'pixel1': 0, 'pixel2': 0, 'pixel3': 0, 'pixel4': 0},
 {'label': 1, 'pixel1': 0, 'pixel2': 0, 'pixel3': 0, 'pixel4': 0},
 {'label': 2, 'pixel1': 0, 'pixel2': 0, 'pixel3': 0, 'pixel4': 0},
 {'label': 3, 'pixel1': 0, 'pixel2': 0, 'pixel3': 0, 'pixel4': 1},
 {'label': 4, 'pixel1': 0, 'pixel2': 0, 'pixel3': 0, 'pixel4': 0},
 {'label': 5, 'pixel1': 0, 'pixel2': 0, 'pixel3': 0, 'pixel4': 5},
 {'label': 6, 'pixel1': 0, 'pixel2': 0, 'pixel3': 0, 'pixel4': 0},
 {'label': 7, 'pixel1': 0, 'pixel2': 0, 'pixel3': 0, 'pixel4': 0},
 {'label': 8, 'pixel1': 0, 'pixel2': 0, 'pixel3': 0, 'pixel4': 0},
 {'label': 9, 'pixel1': 0, 'pixel2': 0, 'pixel3': 0, 'pixel4': 0}])
```

The resulting dataframe would have 10 rows, with each row with a unqiue label. I need this answer to be applicable to larger datasets with 1000's of rows.

Comment: can you please clarify your question? I don't understand what you mean by "I need to remove the same number of rows for each label (0-9)."

Comment: I need there to be an equal distribution of class labels in the resuting dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the first record in each 'label' group.

```
df.groupby('label').head(1)
```

Output:

```
   label  pixel1  pixel2  pixel3  pixel4
0      0       0       0       0       0
1      1       0       0       0       0
2      2       0       0       0       0
3      3       0       0       0       1
4      4       0       0       0       0
5      5       0       0       0       5
6      6       0       0       0       0
7      7       0       0       0       0
8      8       0       0       0       0
9      9       0       0       0       0
```

Or you can get random records from each 'label' group.

```
df.groupby('label', as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.sample(1)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
   label  pixel1  pixel2  pixel3  pixel4
0      0       0       0       0       0
1      1       0       0       0       0
2      2       0       0       0       0
3      3       0       0       0       1
4      4       0       0       0       0
5      5       0       0       0       5
6      6       0       0       0       0
7      7       0       0       0       0
8      8       0       0       0       0
9      9       0       0       0       0
```

Comment: Both solutions work, I prefer the second one. Thanks!

Comment: @BriainODonnell make sure to click the check to indicate that this person has answered your question

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
yourDataFrame.drop_duplicates('label')
```

Answer (score 0):

After you created your `df`, it has 20 rows with each `label` occuring **twice**.

So in order to leave each row **one time** (without repetitions), you can
use: `drop_duplicates` with `subset` = `'label'`.

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset='label', inplace=True); df
```

## Edit

But if you have **various** number of rows with the same `label` (in each,
group with the same label), you have to take other approach:

Start from counting how many times occurs each `label`:

```
df.groupby('label').size()
```

We want to know also the **minimal group count**:

```
minGrpCnt = df.groupby('label').size().min()
```

In order not to lose any group, you can delete *minGrpCnt - 1* rows from
each group.

To find these rows, you can use `cumcount` function, numbering rows in each group, starting **from 0**.

So e.g. if `minGrpCnt` = 2 then you can delete rows with
`cumcount() = 0` (only the first row in each group).

In general case, we are interested in rows with `cumcount() < minGrpCnt - 1`.

We have to find indices of these rows (`df[<predicate>].index`) and drop
rows with these indices.

So to sum up, the command to do your task is:

```
df.drop(df[df.groupby('label').cumcount() < minGrpCnt - 1].index, inplace=True)
```